# I have this program that makes 6x6 matrix. I want to add a piece of code that will scan the matrix and give location of palindrome number

Tags: c#

I wrote this piece of code that makes a simple 6x6 matrix (after taking input from the user) and I have to add a code that will scan the matrix and count for palindromes (if any) and will show their exact location (for example "First palindrome is at row 6 and column 2 \n Second palindrome is at row 2 column 4... etc ) but for that I have to use a "method" and that is where things gets weird for me as I have no experience in doing so. I really hope to get some help here. Thankyou so much.

Here's my matrix code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ArrayMatrix
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i, j;
            int[,] arr1 = new int[6, 6];

            Console.Write("Input elements in the matrix :\n");
            for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("element - [{0},{1}] : ", i, j);
                    arr1[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }
            }

            Console.Write("\nThe matrix is : \n");
            for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("\n");
                for (j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                    Console.Write("{0}\t", arr1[i, j]);
            }
            Console.Write("\n\n");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _First palindrome is at row 6 and column 2  - Second palindrome is at row 2 column 4._ How are you defining a 'palindrome' within your matrix? Do you mean if the matrix entry is, for example, '12321'? What about '1' or '11', do they count?

Comment: Like a simple Palindrome value, like the one that is the same if reversed. So 1 isn't, as 01 reversed is 10 while 11 is a palindrome as 11 reversed is still 11.

Comment: Yes, 12321 will count as a Palindrome

Comment: Sounds like you have enough information to write a `bool IsPalindrome(int value)` method? The [method docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods) should help you get started.

Comment: sadly enough I have seen this guide and even then I have not been able to find a way to implement that into my code :(

Answer (score 1):

So, for a number to be a palindrome by your rules:

- It must be greater than 9
- The sequence of digits must be same the same when reversed.

Here’s an example using [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/):

```
public static bool IsPalindrome(int value)
{
    if (value < 10)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var characters = value.ToString().ToCharArray();

    return characters.SequenceEqual(characters.Reverse());
}
```

Docs:

[SequenceEqual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal)

[Reverse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.reverse)

[ToCharArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray)

Comment: Yes sir I get that, but how do I make it show the output from my matrix? I am very confused,

Comment: Like how do I make it search for Palindrome values from my matrix, and then show its location as well (in correspondence to rows and columns)

Comment: Well, for every element in the matrix - rows and columns - you call this method. That tells you which entries are palindromic, and from that you can construct your output.

Comment: I did try that but it seems to get stuck at execution and says "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array." I don't seem to figure out how to fix that

Comment: See this question: [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f)